# How to delete children when main entity is deleted?

Tags: 8, entities

I am looking for the best way to delete children of my main entity when i delete it.

I have 2 entity type :

> commandes_entity
>
> commandes_ligne_entity ( entity reference to commandes_entity )

The only way i have found is to create a hook_entity_delete :

> Edit :  This is how i delete children :

```
function boutique_commandes_entity_delete(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{
  $query = \Drupal::database()->delete('commandes_lignes_entity');
  $query->condition('commandes_id', $entity->get('id')->value);
  $query->execute();
}
```

Is there another way (maybe better) for delete children ?

Comment: I think you should create a custom delete form that will notify the user of the entities about to be deleted and the submit method should delete all the relevant entities.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)  to react to an entity being deleted, then add a loop over the reference field and use entity delete for the current list item.

Currently on my phone so apoligies for the compact answer.

Comment: um i see, if i can do that with code i prefer. i was looking for another way, maybe without hook.

Comment: Many users prefer not to code ;) , but in that case, your originial idea is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you could overwrite the preDelete() or postDelete() method of your commandes_entity.

For deleting you can also use the delete() methode provided by the EntityInterface:

```
$commandes_lignes_entity = $entity->commandes_id->entity;
$commandes_lignes_entity->delete();
```